# Retrieve an array of image URLs that belong to a gallery

Tags: images, gallery

I am creating an image slider for the gallery post type. The code below works fine with the classic gallery, however when I use the new Gutenberg gallery block the `get_post_gallery_images()` function doesn't retrieve the array of image URLs.

```
$images = get_post_gallery_images();
echo '<div class="image-row">';
    foreach ( $images as $image ) {
        echo '<div class="image-container">';
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" />';
        echo '</div>';
    }
echo '</div>';
```